# Como acessar o email pelo RScript?

Tags: r, email, rscript

Gostaria de saber se através de algum pacote do *R* é possível acessar as caixas de e-mail (*Outlook*, por exemplo) diretamente.

Se for possível, qual pacote devo utilizar?

Answer (score 0):

Kamila, existe um pacote para g-mail:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmailr/index.html